# Dialog theme not used

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have created custom dialog that located in values/styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />

<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And then I wish to use it:

```
final Dialog dialogC = new Dialog(context,R.style.MyDialogTheme);
dialogC.setContentView(R.layout.confirm);
```

I get no errors, but it still uses the default theme. This theme worked perfectly when I used it for an activity that I wished to appear as dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this one, it's work for me

```
dialog3=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog3.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog3.setContentView(R.layout.one_button_dialog4);
```

Comment: But i wish to remove background also